# Programming a button press in one view controller, to load and save a cell in a different table view controller

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios6, xcode4.5

In my application I have a number of view controllers, all of which have a favorite button on. When the favorite button is pressed, I want some information about the view controller to be saved in a separate table view in a different table view controller.

This is my first IOs app, and even after reading about Core Data, I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to go forwards.

How would I go about implementing such a feature?

Thanks for helping a novice out!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store information locally you can use the **NSUserDefaults** class.

On the favorite button action method, save the viewcontroller name in an NSMutableArray using NSUserDefaults

```
    -(IBAction)btnFavouriteClick:(id)sender {

      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      //Get favorited views array (new array will be created if it doesn't  exist)    
      NSMutableArray *favoriteviews = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorite_views_key"];

      //Add current view name to the array
      [favoriteviews addObject:@"viewcontroller_name"];

      //Add the array back in NSUserDefaults
      [defaults setObject:favoriteviews forKey:@"favorite_views_key"];

      //Save NSUserDefaults
      [defaults synchronize];
    }
```

You can retrieve the values using **favorite_views_key** and show them in the UITableView

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  

    //Get favorited views array
    NSMutableArray *favoriteviews = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorite_views_key"];
```

favoriteviews is array of all the favorited views.

Comment: Hi Saravana, 

thank you very much for your response! I am hoping you can help me a little further though. When I implement your code, I get an error of "Use of undeclared identifier 'json' " thrown back at me. 

I'm sure this is due to my lack of experience, could you suggest what I've missed?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I have edited the code above. You can store the favorited view controller name as an array object with a key and then you can retrive it with that key.

Comment: Thank you very much Saravana, your answer really helped me out! Spot on!